# Display view from different controller in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a page in an Asp.NET MVC 3 application.  I have an action in one controller called Alarm. That controller is called Dispatch.  For various reasons, I need to modify this action so it displays its results in a view from another controller called Read.  This view is called Details.

How can I make the Alarm action return that view?  I tried

```
return View( "Read/Details", vm );
```

but that displayed this error message:

> The view 'Read/Details' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Dispatch/Read/Details.aspx ~/Views/Dispatch/Read/Details.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Read/Details.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Read/Details.ascx ~/Views/Dispatch/Read/Details.cshtml ~/Views/Dispatch/Read/Details.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Read/Details.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Read/Details.vbhtml

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use full path instead

```
return View("~/Views/Read/Details.cshtml", vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to an action on another controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", routeValues);
```

Obviously replace the action and controller names with the appropriate values and `routeValues` will contain whatever parameters the action requires.  So if your `vm` variable is just an integer Id, your code would look something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 1234 });
```

Further reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: While the RedirectToAction works, it changes the URL.  I want the different view to display but at the current URL.  Kalyan's answer, as well as one in the other question, do that.

Comment: Ahh, you're right.  I'll leave this answer here in case anyone else is looking for this behavior.